# Join 3 tables in bigquery with no duplication

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to join 3 tables:

```
table 1 
c_id gateway_id timestamp
1    0          2019-01-05 06:53:24 UTC
2    0          2019-01-05 08:51:24 UTC

table 2
gateway_id gateway_name
0          a
1          b

table 3
date         u_id
2022-08-13   1
2022-08-13   2
```

I join from 3 tables. Tabel 1 and 2 on gateway_id and join that two to tables 3 on c_id = u_id. Here's the query i try:

```
WITH
  date_dict AS (
  SELECT
    DATE('2022-08-04') AS start_dt,
    DATE_SUB(current_date, INTERVAL 1 day) AS end_dt),
mp AS(
SELECT 
  a.c_id,
  a.gateway_id,
  b.gateway_name,
  SUM(a.actual_amount) total_p
FROM a
JOIN b USING(gateway_id)
WHERE
  date(a.update_timestamp) between (select start_dt from date_dict) and (select end_dt from date_dict)
  AND b.gateway_source_name = 'Marketplace'
GROUP BY 1,2,3)
SELECT m.c_id, p.u_id, m.gateway_id, m.gateway_name, date, m.total_p
FROM mp m
JOIN p ON m.c_id = CAST(p.u_id AS INT64)
```

But there are duplication in the result like this:

```
c_id    u_id    gateway_id  gateway_name    date_key    total_p
1       1       0           a               2022-08-18  800000
1       1       0           a               2022-08-18  800000
1       1       1           b               2022-08-18  634490
1       1       1           b               2022-08-18  634490
1       1       2           c               2022-08-18  200000
1       1       2           c               2022-08-18  200000
```

When I adding GROUP BY in the last query there are error. I want the result like this:

```
c_id    u_id    gateway_id  gateway_name    date_key    total_p
1       1       0           a               2022-08-18  800000
1       1       1           b               2022-08-18  634490
1       1       2           c               2022-08-18  200000
```

There are no duplication. Any suggestion?

Comment: Without seeing your source, we can't know why you're getting fan-out. The quickest solution is to just SELECT DISTINCT but that may not be the "right" way to do it depending on your source data.

Comment: I have adding the data in every table ya

Comment: Not a great example. Your table names don't match your query and your data is incomplete. Do you get any fan-out when you select from mp by itself? Check each CTE by itself and make sure it's giving you what you expect.

Comment: Can you provide a full schema and sample data of your table?